# DevExpress textbox validation not working as desired

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

I have a text box which has the following requirements:

1. Can be Empty
2. If not empty must be exactly 9 numbers

I would like it so as soon as you type a character into the textbox a message appears saying this is invalid and that message will remain visible without disappearing as long as the validation doesn't pass even while the user is typing into the box. For Example I type 1 into the box and immediately the error appears, then while I type 2345678 the message stays visible even when losing focus on the editor. Then as soon as I add 9 the message disappears. I already have working logic for the validation I just can't seem to get the events to fire how I want. For example if I start typing into the field the error disappears until it loses focus and then it reappears. How to I make it stay even while typing?

```
Html.DevExpress().TextBox(tb =>
{
    tb.Name = "tbAddressChangeDUNS";
    tb.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);
    tb.Properties.ClientSideEvents.KeyUp = "function(s, e) {s.Validate();}";
    tb.Properties.ClientSideEvents.LostFocus = "function(s, e) {s.Validate();}";
    tb.Properties.ClientSideEvents.Validation = @"function(s, e) {
            var duns = e.value;
            if(!duns)
                return;
            if(!IsValidDunsNumber(duns)) {
                e.isValid = false;
                e.errorText = 'Must be exactly 9 digits';
            }
        }";
}).Render();
```

Comment: Maybe change your "LostFocus" by something related to TextChanged ?

Comment: I have tried all of the events under ClientSideEvents and no combination that I can find gives me the behavior described above. Interestingly DevExpress documentation at the link below has a TextChanged event that looks like what I want but but it is not available to me under ClientSideEvents for some reason.

https://documentation.devexpress.com/AspNet/DevExpress.Web.TextBoxClientSideEvents.members

Comment: What you mean by not available ? The inhertance hierarchy is different between LostFocus and TextChanged. LostFocus is available from `EditClientSideEvents`, whereas TextChanged is available from `TextEditClientSideEvents`

Comment: Well either I am blind and just didn't see it or my intellisense wasn't showing it as available before for some reason but now it is. Either way I tried using the TextChanged event and it doesn't do what I want either.

Comment: On DevExpress Documentation, the event validation "is raised when it is required to validate". I would fire this event in the TextChanged handler.

Comment: That is what I tried and it doesn't work. This was my line of code:
tb.Properties.ClientSideEvents.TextChanged = @"function(s, e) {s.Validate();}";

Answer (score 0):

According to my comments, there is a big hint below that should solve your problem :

> You can manually trigger validation at any moment via the [ASPxClientEdit.Validate Method](https://documentation.devexpress.com/AspNet/DevExpress.Web.Scripts.ASPxClientEdit.Validate.method). Handle the [[ASPxClientTextEdit.TextChanged][1] Event](https://documentation.devexpress.com/AspNet/DevExpress.Web.Scripts.ASPxClientTextEdit.TextChanged.event) of the text box editor to execute custom logic (e.g., trigger validation) when its text is changed. I hope this information will help you.

**source :** https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q572171/how-to-implement-custom-validation-on-text-boxes

Comment: This is what I thought too but as I stated in my comments above, adding the following line of code to the editor doesn't work either:

tb.Properties.ClientSideEvents.TextChanged = "function(s, e) {s.Validate();}";